# Microsoft Flow Oracle Connector

Tags: oracle, powerapps, power-automate

According to [this article](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/connecting-to-oracle-database-from-powerapps-flow-and-logic-apps/):

> You can now connect to your Oracle Database from PowerApps, Flow and Logic  Apps.  The Oracle Database connection allows you to list tables, and perform standard create, read, update and delete of rows in an Oracle databases.  In addition, it supports full delegation of PowerApps’ filtering, sorting and other functions.  It does not support triggers or store procedures yet.

The article was written in March 2017.  Does the connector support triggers and stored procedures now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the [latest update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/oracle/) mentioned about added support for Stored Procedures but with some limitations.

> **January 2018**
>   Support Oracle view as read-only table
>   **October 2018**
>   Support Oracle Stored Procedure
>
> **Known issues and limitations**
>   The followings are some of the known limitations of using Oracle connector
>
> 1. When invoking a Stored Procedure on an Oracle server, we have the following limitations:
>      a. OUT parameters are not supported currently.
>      b. Return value is not available since Oracle Stored Procedure does not return any result.
> 2. Oracle Functions are not supported so they are not listed in the UI.
> 3. The response size limit is 8MB.
> 4. Oracle native query is not supported.

Not sure about Trigger (I assume it is in backlog), you can submit the idea for community support votes to get prioritized by Microsoft [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?q=oracle%20connector).